# A non-numeric value encountered in WooThemes_WooCommerce_Per_Product_Shipping_v2_2_6

Tags: php, wordpress

A non-numeric value encountered in

```
WooThemes_WooCommerce_Per_Product_Shipping_v2_2_6/includes/class-wc-shipping-per-product.php on line 148
```

Line 148 code is
`$item_shipping_cost += $rule->rule_item_cost * $values['quantity'];`

I'm not sure what to change, could you pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because at least one of the two variables :

- $values['quantity']
- $rule->rule_item_cost

Is not a numeric type. I suggest you to print the type of to see.